# What does "appear numbered" means in the end of this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

The board has put forward a motion of no confidence in the Chief Executive and his days at the head of the company now **appear numbered**.

Comment: [Merriam-Webster dictionary:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/days%20are%20numbered) 
**days are numbered** *(idiom)* —used to say that someone or something ***will die, fail, or end soon.*** Examples: *The doctors have told me that my days are numbered, He knew that his days as the team's coach were numbered.* In the cited context, ***appear*** (rather than plain, direct ***are***) is just a cautious "hedge" against the possibility that the CEO might *not* have to step down.

Comment: What might be confusing here is the past-participle-as-adjective. You could read it as "his days... appear *to be* numbered." But hey, to make this question more answerable, please edit to show that you've tried a dictionary (looking up "appear" and "numbered" would help), what you found, what confusion remains, and a bit more about why this phrase confuses you. I'm voting to close as lacking details and proof of research; I'll be happy to retract my close vote after you edit.

Comment: The "base" idiom is just *[someone's] **days are numbered*** (not gonna last forever, will end soon). But reporters often need to be careful about making "unqualified" assertions like that when they're really just reporting gossip and speculation. So if you don't understand something in a newspaper or blog that includes ***appear, seem, look like,...*** (such as ***days appear numbered*** here), try switching the verb to [TO BE] before Googling ***define** "days **are** numbered"*.

Comment: We need to give learners a break. I can see how the idiom is complicated.

Answer (score 3):

This is the expression "someone's or something's days are numbered" but with the verb "appear" to indicate this is merely a guess or prediction. NOAD defines the idiom:

> someone or something will not survive or remain in a position of power or advantage for much longer: *my days as director were numbered.*

(For future reference, this was found under the headword "number".)